# Increment an existing value by 10 each new field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I need some help I need to increment the my existing field pick sequence where all a value of 2600, what I need is  that field needs to keep increasing example:

```
picksequence
2600
2610
2620
2630
```

And the query

```
with        test
as
(
select      lc.name as location,
            lc.pickSequence,
            lc.pickSequence + 10 as testing


from        dbo.LocationContainers lc

where       lc.parentId = 8601

)

select      *
from        test


order by    location
```

the query gives this results now

[image]

Comment: You prabably want to add a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY location) * 10`

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`, butyou need to define an ORDEr BY so that you get the proper sequence

> ```
> with        test
> as
> (
> select      lc.name as location,
>             lc.pickSequence,
>
>             lc.pickSequence + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) * 10) as testing
>
>
> from        dbo.LocationContainers lc
>
> where       lc.parentId = 8601
>
> )
>
> select      *
> from        test
>
>
> order by    location
> ```
>
> ```
> location | pickSequence | testing
> :------- | -----------: | ------:
> loc-1    |         2600 |    2610
> loc-2    |         2600 |    2620
> loc-3    |         2600 |    2630
> loc-4    |         2600 |    2640
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29ecac3b75162d3fd71455a999cb2b87)*